# passing user input of html form to express node js without routing to a new page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, imap

I am trying to use imap to search emails in my gmail inbox. It is going to be server side mail parser. To do so, I used express and I want to receive the input of users (from search field) using express. However, all the solutions I searched in the internet use app.post and bring me to a new page. I don't want to show any thing new in user interface. I just want to receive the input of user and give it to a function which performs imap.search. Any help? Here is the code:

index.htm

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_post" method="POST">

 Search: <input type = "text" name = "Search_value">  <br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "SEARCH">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'));
// use body parser to easy fetch post body
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var Imap = require('imap'),
    inspect = require('util').inspect,
    MailParser = require("mailparser").MailParser;
var imap = new Imap({
  user: '***@gmail.com',
  password: '*****',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true
});
var fs = require('fs'), fileStream;
function openInbox(cb) {
  imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}


// route to '/index.htm' to return the html file
app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.htm');
});

//route that receives the post body and returns your computation
app.post('/process_post', function (req, res) {
  passtoserver(req.body, res);
});

app.listen(8081);

function passtoserver(parms, res) {
  //get the parameters based on input name attribute from the html
  //and parse strings to numbers
  var m = parms.Search_value;
 // res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
 res.end();
  openInbox(function(err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;
    imap.search([ 'ALL', ['FROM', m] ], function(err, results) {

    var f = imap.fetch(results, {
      bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)',
      struct: true
    });
    f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
      console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
      var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
      msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
        var buffer = '';
        stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
          buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
        });
        stream.once('end', function() {
          console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)));
        });
      });
      msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
        console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
      });
      msg.once('end', function() {
        console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
      });
    });
    f.once('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
    });
    f.once('end', function() {
      console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
    });
  });
  });

}
imap.connect();
```

After submiting the user input, a new rout called process-post will ope. How to avoid this?

Comment: Hello, if you want to avoid page refresh you can post your data from client to server via [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). Then display some indication to user that data is processed and when got a response notify user what happened

Comment: Could you please tell me how to send data from client to express server with ajax? Actually, I have worked a little with ajax previously, but I had some errors. @codtex

Comment: Samin, [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_3_%E2%80%93_A_Simple_Example) you can see a very basic example using `XMLHttpRequest` object, but note for this example that their button is `type="button"`, if you are using `<button type="submit"></button>` you need to prevent the form to submit. If you want you can use a library for the purpose - for example [**axios**](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or [**jQuery.ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method or something else ...

Comment: The document is helpful, I read it and I understood, thanks. But, It only explains the client side. Now, if I want to receive this httprequest on express server node js, do you know how can I do it? without refreshing @codtex. Thanks

Comment: Your server side code looks fine and will do the job - `app.post('/process_post' ...` will capture the post request. You just return some result that is making sense to you like `res.status(200).json({result: true, data: {some: 1, data: 'here'}, message: 'Success' })` and see what you get as response on the client side - depending on the result you do something

Comment: No, thats my main problem. I don't want to show anything in the /process_post rout. I want to stay in the index.htm page, and then print something at the bottom of the page. As an example, consider gmail search tool. When you write some thing in the search text field, and press search button it does not go to a new page, the results will be shown in the same page you are. @codtex

Comment: So you didn't understood how **AJAX** is working ..... When you do ajax the page is not refreshed then you wait for the response of the server and consider what to do depending on the result

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with:

[https.request()](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) API?

[http.request()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) for secure protocal

Comment: The fact is that I have to use express server, because its a must in my university project.